# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method...or no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I wanted to use create action with ajax on 'index' page. I found some similiar problems here on SO, tried to use it, but no help for me so far. HTML works fine, only JS is a problem.

## walls_controller:

```
def items
  @item = Item.new
  @items = current_user.items
  find_items
  @ads = @items_ads
end

def create
  @items = current_user.items
  find_items
  #@items_ads via find_items method
  @ads = @items_ads  
  @item = current_user.items.build item_params
  current_user.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

## items.html.erb:

```
<div id="items1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h3>Wall of user <%= current_user.name %></h3>
      <div>
        <%= render 'item_form', item: @item %>
      </div>
      Currently you are looking for these items:
      <div>
        <%= render 'items_list', items: @items %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= render 'ads/ads_list', ads: @ads %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## _item_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(item, url: wall_items_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
...
```

First I had error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `items' for #<#<Class:...
```

then I changed create.js.erb from

```
$("#items1").html("<%= render 'items_list', locals: {items: @items} %>");
$("#items1").html("<%= render 'ads_list', locals: {ads: @ads} %> ");
```

to

```
$("#items1").html("<%= render 'items_list', items: @items %>");
$("#items1").html("<%= render 'ads/ads_list', ads: @ads %>");
```

and now it doesn't show me any error, but no visible change when trying JS on browser. Thanks for help.

Comment: try with the first code you have `$("#items1").html("<%= render 'items_list', locals: {items: @items} %>");`, just add the `j` `$("#items1").html("<%= j render('items_list', locals: {items: @items}) %>");`

Answer (score 2):

### Rendering Partials

You can render a partial with local data in two ways:

### Option 1

*The shortcut version*

```
<%= render "my_partial", local_var_1: some_var, local_var_2: another_var %>
```

The shortcut version takes the partial name as the first argument and a hash of local variables as the second parameter.

### Option 2

*The long form version*

This form takes only a single argument in the form of a `Hash` with all the options.

### Don't mix-and-match forms

Doing the following will yield unexpected results

```
<%= render "my_partial", locals: { local_var_1: some_var, local_var_2: another_var } %>
```

Technically here you are using the shortcut version (Option 1), rendering a partial named "my_partial" with a single local variable called `locals`.

You would expect to be able to use `local_var_1` and `local_var_2` within the partial, however you actually only get a single local variable called `locals`.

---

## Rendering Partials in an SJR template

### `escape_javascript` GOTCHA

In a server-generated JavaScript template (SJR), you must remember to use `escape_javascript` whenever you are rendering content which contains HTML.

```
$("#my-selector").html("<%= escape_javascript render('my_partial') %>");
```

Regardless of how you choose to render the partial (i.e. either Option 1 or Option 2 above), you must remember to wrap it in an `escape_javascript` (or its alias `j`) call.

### Helpful Resources

- [Working With JavaScript in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)
- [When to Use `escape_javascript` in an SJR Template](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/when-to-use-escape-javascript-in-an-sjr-template.html?utm_source=stackoverflow)

Comment: Great thanks, but it solved my problem only partly. Although I can now use create.js.erb how I intented, destroy.js.erb ( which should render the same partial) won't show any change.

Comment: Cool! Glad you are making progress. Please post the contents of `destroy.js.erb` and `create.js.erb` and we'll see what the issue is.

Comment: So for simplicity I omitted ads part ... so both look like this:

$("#items1").html("<%= j render 'items_list', items: @items %>");

Comment: And what about the `destroy` action code from the controller? Is it defining an `@items` variable? If so, have you tried simply debugging it using static content, e.g. `$("#items1").html("Test Test");`? If that works, then the problem lies somewhere in your `render` call within the template.

Comment: Finally solved it. I needed to set some variables and method call at the end of create/destroy action. Thanks Carlos.

Comment: Only one last small issue, name of item stays in the form field even after that item was created, what could be wrong?

Comment: Are you refreshing the `<form>` in your SJR template? You'd have to do something like `$("#item_form").html("<%= j render("item_form") %>");` to refresh it

Comment: Yes and I had to set @item = Item.new at the end of create action too. Thanks again :)

Comment: Happy to help :) Just make sure you mark whichever answer you feel is the "solution" so that others can benefit from this post in the future. Good luck!