# Showing duplicate comment on page refresh (after initial AJAX append) [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, duplicates, refresh

Can't seem to figure this one out... In my rails app, I have Post and Comment resources. When a new comment is created, I want to reload the list of comments using AJAX. That part seems to work appropriately—however, when the full page is subsequently reloaded, the list also shows a duplicate of the comment, as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eftbL.png). Any thoughts on what may be causing this?

(note: deleting one of the comments also deletes the duplicate)

> views/users/show.html.haml

```
= form_for([post, post.comments.build], remote: true) do |f|
  = f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Press ENTER to submit...', class: "comment_content", id: "comment_content_#{post.id}"
    - if post.comments
      .comments{ id: "comments_#{post.id}" }
        - post.comments.each do |comment|
          = render post.comments, post: post
```

> views/comments/_comment.html.haml

```
- unless comment.content == nil
  .comment{ id: "comment_#{comment.id}" }
    .user-name
      = link_to comment.user.identities.first.nickname, comment.user
    .comment-content
      = comment.content
        - if comment.user == current_user
          = link_to post_comment_path(post, comment), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, remote: true do
            %i.fa.fa-close
```

> controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post

    def create  
      @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
      @comment.user_id = current_user.id

      if @comment.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.js
        end
      else
        render root_path
      end
    end

  ...
```

> views/comments/create.js.erb

```
$('#comments_<%= @post.id %>').append("<%=j render @post.comments, post: @post, comment: @comment %>");
$('#comment_content_<%= @post.id %>').val('')
```

## Update

Following @uzaif's suggestion, I replaced ".append" with ".html". This fixed the problem only if I also moved the code out of the _comment partial. Not really an ideal solution... I'd still like to know if/how I could fix the problem and keep my individual comment partial.

Comment: instead of append try to html which will replace your whole `div`

Comment: Good thought, but had the same result

Comment: @uzaif so actually, that fixes the problem if I don't have a "_comment" partial (i.e. if I stick that code back in the "show" view). Not really an ideal solution, but it'll get the job done for now :)

Comment: do you have single comment partial?

Comment: @uzaif I did—that's shown above under "views/comments/_comment.html.haml". Seems to work when I don't use a partial, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

You are seeing duplicate comments because you are inadvertently rendering your comments twice.

```
- post.comments.each do |comment|
  = render post.comments, post: post
```

Calling `render` and passing a collection as the first argument instructs Rails to render **all** of the comments. Internally Rails will iterate over each comment and render it using the object's partial.

By wrapping this `render` call (which already has a loop in it) within *another* loop, you are actually rendering each comment twice.

## The Solution

Remove the outer `post.comments.each` loop and just let the `render` method do it's thing.

```
= render post.comments
```

Rails knows to pass along an local variable named `comment` to each partial, and you should be able to reference the original post by calling `comment.post` (assuming comment `belongs_to :post`).

## Be careful how you call `render`

There are a couple different ways to render partials with data from a collection. **Make sure you know which one you are using and don't mix-and-match them**.

I describe this in [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40412677/1219460).

## Resources

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40412677/1219460

Comment: Thank you! Although Rails actually didn't pass along the `post` variable, so I ended up explicitly stating it. Aside from that detail, your solution solved my problem.

Comment: Ah yes I mistakenly wrote that it would pass `post` as a local variable but since we are rendering `post.comments` it will pass along a `comment` variable instead. You should be able to reference the original post through the comment by calling `comment.post`. I updated my answer above with that clarification. In any case, glad I could help!